# What's the dimension of the space formed by taking a union of projective lines between two spaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I've read that the subspace formed by taking the union of all projective lines that join a point of $\mathbb{P}^{l}$ with a point of $\mathbb{P}^{m}$, where $\mathbb{P}^{l}$ and $\mathbb{P}^{m}$ are both in $\mathbb{P}^{n}$, has dimension l + m + 1. Why exactly is this the case?

Comment: Is there a relation between your $\mathbb{P}^l$ and $\mathbb{P}^m$ i.e. are they embedded into a common space or is one a subspace of the other?

Comment: They are both in the same space but can be distinct.

Comment: Well, it's spanned by lines connecting a point in $\mathbf{P}^l$ to a point in $\mathbf{P}^m$, so there is an $(l + m)$-dimensional space of such lines ($l$ dimensions of choices of a point in $\mathbf{P}^l$, and $m$ dimensions of choices of a point in $\mathbf{P}^m$). Then, once you choose such a line, there is $1$ dimension worth of points along the line you chose, so the entire space you are defining has dimension $l + m + 1$.